# Error when using ruby-oci with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oracle

OCIError: ORA-12516: TNS:listener could not find available handler with matching protocol stack
    oci8.c:267:in oci8lib.bundle

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this, the suggestion is to increase your processes & sessions http://justbarebones.blogspot.com/2008/11/ora-12516-tnslistener-could-not-find.html may solve your problem ?